# Memory issue loading raster into numpy array

Tags: arcpy, raster, numpy, image-classification

I am trying to open a historical imagery tiff dataset into a numpy array so I can do some image processing on it afterwards. However, it gives me 'unspecified error' when trying to run the (very) short code. Is this a memory issue? Or am I missing a crucial step? I have put a screenshot of what I'm working with below.[image: here is my code so far, again it is very short]

```
import numpy as np
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
import arcpy.sa as sa
arcpy.CheckOutExtension("Spatial")
env.workspace = r"Z:\adit\Desktop\2020-2021\Remote Sensing\project\data\1942_Aerials_Central_Sonoma_County"
env.overwriteOutput = 1

historical_imagery = "1942_Central_Sonoma_County.tif"
historical_imagery_rast = sa.Raster(historical_imagery)

#print historical_imagery_rast.mean
#print historical_imagery_rast.standardDeviation

hist_image_raster = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(historical_imagery_rast)
```

Comment: How big is it? Do you run out of memory? Have you tried `historical_imagery_rast = sa.Raster(r"Z:\adit\Desktop\2020-2021\Remote Sensing\project\data\1942_Aerials_Central_Sonoma_County\1942_Central_Sonoma_County.tif")`

Comment: Why would this work? Genuinely curious.